# print each subfolder and each files of subfolders php

Tags: php

This is the file structure in my server:

```
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-a/file-01.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-a/file-02.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-a/file-03.pdf

htdocs/pdf/a/sub-b/file-01.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-b/file-02.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-b/file-03.pdf

htdocs/pdf/a/sub-c/file-01.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-c/file-02.pdf
htdocs/pdf/a/sub-c/file-03.pdf
```

and so on, well, I would like to print a list of any file and any subfolder like this:

```
<h3>sub-a</h3>
<ul>
<li>file-01.pdf</li>
<li>file-02.pdf</li>
<li>file-03.pdf</li>
</ul>

<h3>sub-b</h3>
<ul>
<li>file-01.pdf</li>
<li>file-02.pdf</li>
<li>file-03.pdf</li>
</ul>

<h3>sub-c</h3>
<ul>
<li>file-01.pdf</li>
<li>file-02.pdf</li>
<li>file-03.pdf</li>
</ul>
```

my matter is i don't know how to get the list in php code.
anybody can help me?

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at readdir and scandir: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php. some great examples there too. 
maybe something like this could work (you will need to tweek somewhat - original written for windows sorry):

```
$dir = "htdocs/pdf/a/";
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {                  
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
      if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
          $dir2 = "htdocs/pdf/a/".$file."/";
          echo "<h3>".ucwords(str_replace("-"," ",$file))."</h3><ul>";  
          if ($handle2 = opendir($dir2)) {
              while (false !== ($file2 = readdir($handle2))) {
                if ($file2 != "." && $file2 != "..") {                                                                                                          
                  echo "<li>".$file2."</li>";

                }
              }
            closedir($handle2);
          }
          echo "</ul><hr size='1'>";
      }
  }                 
closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much
If you are interested, this is the final result (with a few changes to HTML)
http://www.amministrazioni-zucchetti.it/protezione/CM_acerbi_46_test.php